# Mobile App with Cert Pinning - SSL Cert on DMZ box with trusted CA vs my own CA

Tags: security, ssl, https, ca, pinning

I am developing a mobile app with certificate pinning.  I will have a box in the DMZ that will proxy my requests.  Should this server have a cert from a trusted CA or can I use the one I generated from my own CA?

What would be the benefits of using a trusted CA from a mobile client?

Also, I will hit several different servers afterward that will be using my own CA generated cert.  Should I pin those as well?  I am assuming yes, that pinning both will be best even within the network.  But is the necessary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use your own CA you gave to manage the revocation process yourself, which is hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a custom CA, it means you will have to either:

- Provision all the mobile devices that will use your App with your custom CA. If you don't control the mobile devices, this will be impossible to do and pushing a CA to a device's trust store is a liability anyway.
- Disable the system's default certificate validation so that the custom CA is accepted by your App, and then re-validate the server's chain and do pinning. It is close to impossible to get this right so you will most likely end up with an insecure HTTPS connection.

Do buy a certificate from a trusted CA.

For the connections between the proxy and the internal servers, you could implement SSL pinning but it is less of a priority as the attack surface is reduced, compared to the mobile clients.